# Finding and removing consecutive repeated intervals in numpy array

Tags: python, numpy

**Problem:** I need to find repeated values within a tolerance range, and replace them with NaNs.  The function I have pasted in below can do this, but it is essentially O(n^2) time and I am (almost) certain this can be done in O(n) time.  A typical array is > 500k samples, so runtime is important.

**What it should do:** For example if you have an array such as `[1,2,3,3,3,3,3,1,2,3]` and tolerance = 0, then you'd get back:
`[1,2,nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, 1,2,3]`.
If you have tolerance = 0.1 and the array is `[1,2, 2.95, 3, 2.95, 3, 3.05, 1,2,3]` you'd also get back `[1,2,nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, 1,2,3]`.

**Slow working example**

```
def find_and_remove_runs(data, n_repeats, tol):
    indices_to_null = []
    for i in range(len(data)-n_repeats):
        diff = abs(data[(i+1):] - data[i])
        end_point = np.argwhere(diff > tol)[0] + 1
        if end_point >= n_repeats:
            indices_to_null.append(tuple((i, int(end_point))))

    if len(indices_to_null) > 0:
        for i in range(len(indices_to_null)):
            data[indices_to_null[i][0]:(
                indices_to_null[i][0] + indices_to_null[i][1])] = np.nan
```

For those who are interested, this is data from a moving sensor... the sensor gets stuck from time to time leading to repeat measurements.  The sensor will have a bit of variance even when measuring the same spot, hence the need for the tolerance on repeats.

Comment: `find_and_remove_runs(data, 2, 0.6)` with `data = [1.0,1.5,2.0,2.5,3.0,3.5,3.0,2.5,2.0,3,4,5]` give a lot of NaN. Is it what you expect? What is supposed to be `n_repeats` in your code? Is it mandatory?

Comment: @JérômeRichard the n_repeats is the number of times a value is repeated before it is eliminated.  For example, we might have a value repeat a small number of times just because that is correct, but when we see, for example 20 repeats in a row that is extremely unlikely and probably due to the sensor getting stuck and reading same value several times in a row.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The rule to clear an element of the source array can be expressed
as a logical *OR* of 2 conditions:

- the previous element (if exists) is close to the current element,
- the next element (if exists) is close to the current element.

"Is close to" means that the absolute value from the difference between
both elements is less or equal to the tolerance (*tol*).

To present a more instructive example, I defined the source array so
that it contains sequences of "close" elements also at both ends:

```
data = np.array([1, 1, 2, 2.95, 3, 2.95, 3, 3.05, 1, 2, 3, 3, 3])
```

To get the expected result, define the following function:

```
def clearRuns(data, tol):
    isNextSame = np.abs(np.diff(data,       prepend=np.nan))       <= tol
    isPrevSame = np.abs(np.diff(data[::-1], prepend=np.nan))[::-1] <= tol
    indToClear = np.logical_or(isNextSame, isPrevSame)
    return np.where(indToClear, np.nan, data)
```

Then run it:

```
result = clearRuns(data, 0.05)
```

The result is:

```
array([nan, nan,  2., nan, nan, nan, nan, nan,  1.,  2., nan, nan, nan])
```

It should run **much** faster than your solution.

Comment: This was close enough to get me on the right path.  Thanks!